# MySQL SELECT records WHERE if value = 'E' ELSE value = 'N'

Tags: mysql, sql

Imagine the following table:

```
| my_id | my_status |        my_title |               my_desc |
|-------|-----------|-----------------|-----------------------|
|     1 |         N |     Hello World | This is a description |
|     2 |         N |     Hello again |             Blah blah |
|     3 |         N |     This is fun |  I like StackExchange |
|     3 |         E | This edited fun |  I love StackExchange |
|     4 |         N |         Goodbye |     Last record here. |
```

Normal records have "N" in the my_status column. When an entry is edited, I created a new record marked with "E". Once an edit is approved, I delete the original N record and update the E record to be an N record. It's basically an edit approval system.

Now I want to query that table and show records with a unique id that are marked with 'E' if they exist, otherwise return the standard 'N' record.  So the ultimate result should be:

```
| my_id | my_status |        my_title |               my_desc |
|-------|-----------|-----------------|-----------------------|
|     1 |         N |     Hello World | This is a description |
|     2 |         N |     Hello again |             Blah blah |
|     3 |         E | This edited fun |  I love StackExchange |
|     4 |         N |         Goodbye |     Last record here. |
```

I  am sure this must be possible in one query but it is eluding me right now. (It's Friday afternoon, 33 degrees in the office and my brain is melting).

I am imagining something like

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE IF EXISTS (my_status='E') ELSE (my_status='N')
```

(I know that's not valid SQL but it hopefully indicates the gist of what I want to achieve).

SQL Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1b049/1

Comment: It's not how I think I'd do it. I'd just store all the edits. The latest version is simply the latest approved edit.

Answer (score 2):

you can group by the id and then take the smallest status ('N' is greater than 'E') for each id

```
select t1.*
from my_table t1
join
(
  SELECT my_id, min(my_status) as status 
  FROM my_table 
  GROUP BY my_id
 ) t2 on t1.my_id = t2.my_id and t1.my_status = t2.status
```

#### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1b049/28)

Comment: It should be `MIN(my_status)`. :-)

Comment: @juergend why do you use join instead of SELECT *, min(my_status)

Comment: @AlexanderMadyuskin: Because that would return undefined results.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to ensure that there doesn't exists any row with the same my_id and my_status = 'E':

```
SELECT * FROM my_table t
where not (my_status = 'N' and exists (
  select 1 from my_table where my_id = t.my_id 
  and my_status = 'E')
)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1b049/6)

Answer (score 1):

I think a simple way to do this is with `union all`:

```
select f.*
from following f
where f.status = 'E'
union all
select f.*
from following f
where not exists (select 1
                  from following f2
                  where f2.my_id = f.my_id and f2.status = 'E'
                 );
```

The first subquery gets all the `E`s.  The second gets all `N`s that don't have a corresponding `E`.  Performance should be very good with indexes on `status` and `my_id, status`.

Answer (score 1):

group by and MIN function (since 'E' < 'N'):

```
SELECT my_id, MIN(my_status), my_title, my_desc FROM my_table group by my_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Much less elegant than juergen's answer :

```
SELECT * FROM my_table AS t
INNER JOIN (SELECT my_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM my_table GROUP BY 1) AS t2
  ON t.my_id = t2.my_id
WHERE my_status = "E" OR t2.cnt = 1;
```

It means basically saying "if it's an 'E' take it otherwise, check if there is only one row with this my_id, if yes it means that there is just a 'N' row".